# Get value from tag HTML other site

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I wanna get value from other site based on class tag html. Specific value, we can see the picture below [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkn4B.png)

And I get them with PHP code below, but I didn't get it

```
$url = 'http://www.liburnasional.com/kalender-2018/';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$first_step = explode( '<time class="libnas-calendar-holiday-datemonth">' , $content );
$second_step = explode("</time>" , $first_step[0] );
print_r($second_step);
```

Please help me, thanks in advance guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `HTML DOM` parser you can get element.

Check below code, Hope it'll helpful !

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors',0);
    $elements = array();
    $url = 'http://www.liburnasional.com/kalender-2018/';
    $content = file_get_contents($url);
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($content);
    foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('time') as $element){
        $elements[] = $element->nodeValue;
    }
    $doc->saveHTML();

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($elements);
    exit;
?>
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1 Januari 2018
    [1] => 16 Februari 2018
    [2] => 18 Maret 2018
    [3] => 30 Maret 2018
    [4] => 13 April 2018
    [5] => 1 Mei 2018
    [6] => 10 Mei 2018
    [7] => 29 Mei 2018
    [8] => 1 Juni 2018
    [9] => 15 - 16 Juni 2018
    [10] => 17 Agustus 2018
    [11] => 22 Agustus 2018
    [12] => 12 September 2018
    [13] => 20 November 2018
    [14] => 25 Desember 2018
)
```

**Notes**

> 1) I have set `ini_set('display_errors',0);` because of some of your `HTML` code not closing properly.
>
> 2) `nodeValue` only get element value. If you want to get other property check through `print_r($element)` in `foreach` loop.
>
> 3) I have set array of an all founded element value. You can change it !